# how to add georeferencing to a jpeg file

Tags: jpeg, gps

First of all, I'm completely new to Ubuntu.

My Garmin handheld GPS is recognized by Ubuntu and I am able to access the file. I wish to add a Jpeg map to the device and I'm running into problems.

I downloaded QLandkarteGT and when I try to upload my map it keeps giving me the same error message which says "This Map doesn't contain Georeferences". I have the coordinates for the map, but I have no clue of how to add them to the Jpeg file. And if I some how find out how to add the coordinates the stupid jpeg won't even copy and paste to the maps file...... I'm going crazy. I may just give up on ubuntu all together... ahhhhhh

Comment: There's some support for Linux over at the Garmin forums - you may be able to find what you are looking for there.  https://forums.garmin.com/activity.php